# $R$ regarded as $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ be $R$ regarded as $R$-module is usual way.

> Then the submodule $N=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ is not finitely generated

Hint: for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $e_n=(0,…,0,1,0,…)\in N$ (the $1$ is on the $n-$th position).

Please help me to prove this result. Thanks in advance

Comment: Again? How many times will you ask the same question?

Answer (score 0):

Another hint: An element of $N$ has only finitely many non-zero entries. If $N$ is finitely generated, then the collection of all linear combination of those generators can only make finitely many of the $e_n$.

Comment: i don't see how to use this hint can you please help me more? i will will greatfull if you do so. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Arthur I think you mixed up $M$ and $N$.

Comment: @asdq That I did. Thank you.

Comment: any linear combination of those generatorsis infinite?

Comment: @siwar How many of the $e_n$'s can possibly be a linear combination of the chosen generators?

Comment: infinite $e_n$?

Comment: @siwar No, exactly the opposite. Only finitely many. I thought the fact that they gave that as a hint would tell you that.

Comment: and if so how does that give a contadiction?

Comment: @siwar If only finitely many of the $e_n$ can be generated, but there are infinitely many $e_n$ in the module, then our set of generators isn't really a set of generators, is it?

Comment: yes can you write those details in your answer before that i click to accept the answer?

Comment: in your answer you didn't rewrite where is the contradiction

Comment: @siwar You are right, I didn't. I left that as an esercise to the reader.

Comment: I thinks you can only add '' but there are infinitely many $e_n$ in the module, then our set of generators isn't really a set of generators, is it'' to have a complete answer

Comment: @siwar But I don't want to do that. It still says "hint" up there, although I think it's almost too substantial now to deserve such a name.

Comment: ok i have an other question : $M$ here is it cyclic? if so why?

Comment: @siwar Yes, it is. Because it can be generated by a single element. You can try to find such an element yourself, because I think you need the practice. Hint: The answer is the same for any commutative, unital ring as a module over itself, so you can do it in full generality if you want.

Comment: is it generated by $(1,1,1,1,1..............)$

Comment: @siwar Yup, that's the one. You can throw in a few $-1$ here and there if you feel like it, so there are multiple possible choices.

Comment: when you said ''then the collection of all linear combination of those generators can only make finitely many of the $e_n$'' how do you justify that?

Comment: @siwar I honestly think that this is something you ought to think about and figure out on your own. But since you clearly don't want to do that, I can give you a few pointers. Say we have a finite number of elements $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in N$. Each of them only has a finite number of non-zero entries. If an entry is $0$ in all of the $x_i$, then it is $0$ in any linear combination of the $x_i$. So if you want to make $e_n$, you need at least one of the $x_i$ to have a non-zero entry number $n$. You only have finitely many of those.